# Why generating entities from database postgresql raise a lot of error?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, annotations, mapping

I generate entities from the dump of the database `PostgreSQL` using JPA persistence in IntelliJ, this is a lot of error in mapping *( name of the join column, the composite keys..)*, is there a way to fix them automatically  I have 100 tables
here is an example where an error is thrown, the error is" Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [ressource] contains physical column name [id_modele] referred to by multiple physical column names: : [id_modele], [idModele]

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "ressource", schema = "public", catalog = "pfeDb")
   public class RessourceEntity {
    private String idRessource;
     private String nomIhmRessource;
   private String identifiant;
   private String idPeuplement;
     private String idModele;
   private String nomModele;
   private String idDomaine;
  private String fonctionTechnique;
      private String typeRessource;
   private Integer idImage;
    private String commentaire;
   private Integer idDetailSynoptique;
    private ModeleEntity modeleByIdModele;
   private SynoptiqueEntity synoptiqueByIdDetailSynoptique;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_ressource", nullable = false, length = 234)
         public String getIdRessource() {
         return idRessource;
   }

public void setIdRessource(String idRessource) {
    this.idRessource = idRessource;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "nom_ihm_ressource", nullable = false, length = 128)
public String getNomIhmRessource() {
    return nomIhmRessource;
}

public void setNomIhmRessource(String nomIhmRessource) {
    this.nomIhmRessource = nomIhmRessource;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "identifiant", nullable = false, length = 64)
public String getIdentifiant() {
    return identifiant;
}

public void setIdentifiant(String identifiant) {
    this.identifiant = identifiant;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "id_peuplement", nullable = false, length = 102)
public String getIdPeuplement() {
    return idPeuplement;
}

public void setIdPeuplement(String idPeuplement) {
    this.idPeuplement = idPeuplement;
}

@Basic

public String getIdModele() {
    return idModele;
}

public void setIdModele(String idModele) {
    this.idModele = idModele;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "nom_modele", nullable = false, length = 64)
public String getNomModele() {
      return nomModele;
    }

     public void setNomModele(String nomModele) {
    this.nomModele = nomModele;
        }

     @Basic
      @Column(name = "id_domaine", nullable = true, length = 88)
     public String getIdDomaine() {
    return idDomaine;
         }

        public void setIdDomaine(String idDomaine) {
  this.idDomaine = idDomaine;
       }

       @Basic
      @Column(name = "fonction_technique", nullable = false, length = 64)
      public String getFonctionTechnique() {
      return fonctionTechnique;
 }

      public void setFonctionTechnique(String fonctionTechnique) {
        this.fonctionTechnique = fonctionTechnique;
     }

      @Basic
   @Column(name = "type_ressource", nullable = false, length = 8)
    public String getTypeRessource() {
     return typeRessource;
    }

     public void setTypeRessource(String typeRessource) {
      this.typeRessource = typeRessource;
    }

   @Basic
      @Column(name = "id_image", nullable = true)
     public Integer getIdImage() {
       return idImage;
  }

    public void setIdImage(Integer idImage) {
        this.idImage = idImage;
     }

     @Basic
     @Column(name = "commentaire", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getCommentaire() {
      return commentaire;
   }

    public void setCommentaire(String commentaire) {
       this.commentaire = commentaire;
       }

     @Basic
     @Column(name = "id_detail_synoptique", nullable = true)
      public Integer getIdDetailSynoptique() {
     return idDetailSynoptique;
     }

      public void setIdDetailSynoptique(Integer idDetailSynoptique) {
       this.idDetailSynoptique = idDetailSynoptique;
    }

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "id_modele",  nullable = false)
      public ModeleEntity getModeleByIdModele() {
    return modeleByIdModele;
}

public void setModeleByIdModele(ModeleEntity modeleByIdModele) {
    this.modeleByIdModele = modeleByIdModele;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_detail_synoptique")
    public SynoptiqueEntity getSynoptiqueByIdDetailSynoptique() {
        return synoptiqueByIdDetailSynoptique;
     }

   public void setSynoptiqueByIdDetailSynoptique(SynoptiqueEntity 
     synoptiqueByIdDetailSynoptique) {
       this.synoptiqueByIdDetailSynoptique = 
   synoptiqueByIdDetailSynoptique;
   }
 }
```

and the other class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "modele", schema = "public", catalog = "pfeDb")
  public class ModeleEntity {
    private String idModele;
     private String nomModele;
     private Integer idImage;
   private String idVersionCatalogue;
     private String idCategorie;
    private String idDomaine;
        private String idTypeModele;
        private boolean accesUnique;
     private String regle;
     private String reglesGenerees;
      private String commentaire;
    private Integer objetId;
     private Boolean interfaceCristal;
      private ObjetModeleEntity objetModeleByObjetId;
    private Collection<RessourceEntity> ressourcesByIdModele;

     @Id
  public String getIdModele() {
      return idModele;
  }
    public void setIdModele(String idModele) {
       this.idModele = idModele;
      }
        @Basic
  public String getNomModele() {
    return nomModele;
     }
   public void setNomModele(String nomModele) {
      this.nomModele = nomModele;
      }
     @Basic
     public Integer getIdImage() {
      return idImage;
     }
    public void setIdImage(Integer idImage) {
     this.idImage = idImage;
     }
   @Basic
    public String getIdVersionCatalogue() {
       return idVersionCatalogue;
   }
   public void setIdVersionCatalogue(String idVersionCatalogue) {
     this.idVersionCatalogue = idVersionCatalogue;
     }
    @Basic
  public String getIdCategorie() {
     return idCategorie;
 }
    public void setIdCategorie(String idCategorie) {
     this.idCategorie = idCategorie;
     }
      @Basic
     public String getIdDomaine() {
        return idDomaine;
  }

      public void setIdDomaine(String idDomaine) {
         this.idDomaine = idDomaine;
      }
     @Basic
       public String getIdTypeModele() {
      return idTypeModele;
   }

 public void setIdTypeModele(String idTypeModele) {
    this.idTypeModele = idTypeModele;
    }
  @Basic
    @Column(name = "acces_unique", nullable = false)
      public boolean isAccesUnique() {
       return accesUnique;
     }

        public void setAccesUnique(boolean accesUnique) {
         this.accesUnique = accesUnique;
      }

      @Basic

    public String getRegle() {
         return regle;
      }

       public void setRegle(String regle) {
          this.regle = regle;
     }

     @Basic

   public String getReglesGenerees() {
         return reglesGenerees;
     }

   public void setReglesGenerees(String reglesGenerees) {
       this.reglesGenerees = reglesGenerees;
}

     @Basic

   public String getCommentaire() {
       return commentaire;
     }

   public void setCommentaire(String commentaire) {
         this.commentaire = commentaire;
      }

     @Basic

        public Integer getObjetId() {
         return objetId;
  }

        public void setObjetId(Integer objetId) {
       this.objetId = objetId;
    }

      @Basic

    public Boolean getInterfaceCristal() {
      return interfaceCristal;
     }

     public void setInterfaceCristal(Boolean interfaceCristal) {
       this.interfaceCristal = interfaceCristal;
     }
  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "objet_id")
   public ObjetModeleEntity getObjetModeleByObjetId() {
    return objetModeleByObjetId;
  }
  public void setObjetModeleByObjetId(ObjetModeleEntity 
 objetModeleByObjetId) {
    this.objetModeleByObjetId = objetModeleByObjetId;
     }
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "modeleByIdModele")
 public Collection<RessourceEntity> getRessourcesByIdModele() {
    return ressourcesByIdModele;
   }
  public void setRessourcesByIdModele(Collection<RessourceEntity> 
   ressourcesByIdModele) {
         this.ressourcesByIdModele = ressourcesByIdModele;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share some of the errors you get?

Comment: @LajosArpad erreur in mapping like: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table  contains physical column name  referred to by multiple physical column names:....

Comment: @LajosArpad and Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table contains physical column name [ referred to by multiple physical column names

Comment: You have duplicate mappings. Probably the same mapping is defined in annotations as well as in the Hibernate config file. Can you edit your question and add some code you have?

Comment: @LajosArpad the entities had generated automatically from the database, I did do the mapping manually

Comment: I had do the same steps mentioned in this site https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000751864-Generate-Persistence-Mapping-by-Database-Schema-Detail-settings-for-Entity-Class

Comment: @LajosArpad I edit the question

Comment: Can you edit your question with your mapping?

Comment: @LajosArpad the mapping is at the bottom of the code

Comment: AnoirEl, I have meant the mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml. I am on the opinion that you have your mapping in that xml file and your Java code notations as well, resulting in the error. That's the most common cause.

Comment: I used spring boot, I have not the file hibernate.cfg.xml